# How to style oembedded tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, oembed

I have this script (using oembed):

```css
<script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resolve").click(function() {
    var url=$("#retweet_form_url").val();
    if (url=="") {
      $(".controls").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
      $("#embed").show();
      $.ajax( {
        url: "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?maxwidth=840&maxheight=1000&url="+url, dataType: "jsonp", success: function(data) {
          $("#embed").html(data.html);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}) 
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="retweet_form_url" />
<button id="resolve">Get</button>
<div id="embed"></div>
```

It works, user input url of tweet and it tweet shows up, but I want to make it with no borders.. How?

Comment: The `#resolve` button without borders? Try using `border: none;` to remove the borders using `css` for styling.

Comment: No, embedded tweet comes out, with its default border.. how can I remova that? That not my css.. when you go to some tweet and click embed tweet, you get a code, there you can add data-chrome=""noborders" and its done... but in my case I cant add that cos I dont really have that part of the code.